# ¿Por qué en la terminal de Spyder me da error "No module named 'pandas'" si ya tengo el módulo instalado?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, ide, spyder

Hola a todos los que lleguen hasta aquí!!!
¿Por qué en la terminal de Spyder me da error "No module named 'pandas'" si ya tengo el módulo instalado?, incluso desde ipython en la terminal y desde otros IDE's ya he utilizado la librería.

Comment: Puede que te encuentres en un **entorno** distinto, en el que no lo tengas instalado, en tal caso, solo tienes que volverlo a instalar.

Comment: Normalmente sucede porque tu máquina puede tener una versión de python instalada diferente a la que usa Spyder, por lo tanto éste no puede "ver" pandas. Para eliminar esta hipótesis en tu terminal escribe python --version y repite la operación en la consola que te da Spyder. ¿Son los mismos?

Comment: efectivamente mis versiones no son las mismas. En el pc tengo la 3.10 mientras que spyder me arroja 3.7.9. Que puedo hacer?